# How to pass a GridViewColumnHeader object to a method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview that pulls a bunch of computer numbers and information from a database and displays it. I have a little menu that will filter this listview. Currently, clicking the columns sorts the listview by ascending/descending, but I want this function to be triggered by radio buttons.
I'm basically trying to trigger the GridViewColumnHeader_Click method from the radiobutton method. Here is the GridViewColumnHeader_Click method:

```
                    private GridViewColumnHeader listViewSortCol = null;
                    private SortAdorner listViewSortAdorner = null;

        private void GridViewColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
            string sortBy = column.Tag.ToString();

            if (listViewSortCol != null)
            {
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Remove(listViewSortAdorner);
                lstView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            }

            ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            if (listViewSortCol == column && listViewSortAdorner.Direction == newDir)
                newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;

            listViewSortCol = column;
            listViewSortAdorner = new SortAdorner(listViewSortCol, newDir);
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Add(listViewSortAdorner);
            lstView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortBy, newDir));
        }
```

```
        private void RbLocation_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewColumnHeader_Click(sender, RoutedEventArgs e);

        }
```

```
                            <RadioButton x:Name="rbP2L" Content="P2L" MinWidth="40" Checked="RbP2L_Checked"/>
                            <RadioButton x:Name="rbAssy" Content="Assembly" Checked="RbAssy_Checked"/>
                            <RadioButton x:Name="rbLocation" Content="Location"   MinWidth="40" Checked="{Binding GridViewColumnHeader_Click}"/>
```

I tried to do the same thing with a binding, not not sure if that's the right way. I was getting a error when trying to do a binding:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.'
```

I think this doesn't work because I'm not binding it to anything, because it's an event.

The listview is defined as such:

```
        <ListView Name="lstView" SelectionChanged="lstView_SelectionChanged_1" MouseDoubleClick="LstView_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGray" Margin="10,10,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PCID}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                    <TextBlock Text="PCID" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
                                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductionArea}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="ProductionArea" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click">
                                    <TextBlock Text="ProductionArea"></TextBlock>
                                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Type" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Type"></TextBlock>
                                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Location" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Location"></TextBlock>
                                </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I figured I could use the tags to point to the header since everything has the same name, but I haven't been able to figure out the right wording. For example, how do I pass the Location header into the GridViewColumnHeader_Click method from outside of the click event? Thanks in advance, very stuck on this one.

Comment: Why not write code handles the radio button change and sorts the collectionview the listview itemssource is bound to?   Then you don't have to find the column header and try simulating a click.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand what your problem is. In fact, you already have everything implemented.

Just in case, I'll show you an example.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace Core2022.SO.AlexD.ManageGridViewColumn
{
    public class SomeItem
    {
        public string Word { get; }
        public int Value { get; }

        public SomeItem(string word, int value)
        {
            Word = word;
            Value = value;
        }

        private static ObservableCollection<SomeItem>? _itemsExample;
        public static ObservableCollection<SomeItem> ItemsExample
        {
            get
            {
                if (_itemsExample is null)
                {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    _itemsExample = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>
                    (
                        "How to pass a GridViewColumnHeader object to a method?"
                        .Split()
                        .Select(word => new SomeItem(word, random.Next()))
                    ); 
                }
                return _itemsExample;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.AlexD.ManageGridViewColumn.ManagerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.AlexD.ManageGridViewColumn"
        xmlns:specialized="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Specialized;assembly=netstandard"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
        xmlns:componentmodel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ManagerWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="itemsView" Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Static local:SomeItem.ItemsExample}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Word">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Word}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="2">
            <TextBlock Text="SortDirection"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Column"/>
             <ComboBox x:Name="directionsView"
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                      SelectionChanged="OnDirectionChanged">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <componentmodel:ListSortDirection>Ascending</componentmodel:ListSortDirection>
                        <componentmodel:ListSortDirection>Descending</componentmodel:ListSortDirection>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
           <ComboBox x:Name="propertiesView"
                      SelectedIndex="0"
                      SelectionChanged="OnPropertyChanged">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <specialized:StringCollection>
                        <sys:String>Un Sort</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Word</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Value</sys:String>
                    </specialized:StringCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Core2022.SO.AlexD.ManageGridViewColumn
{
    public partial class ManagerWindow : Window
    {
        public ManagerWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string oldProperty = string.Empty;
        private ListSortDirection oldDirection;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string property = (string)propertiesView.SelectedItem;
            itemsView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            if (property is not nameof(SomeItem.Word) and not nameof(SomeItem.Value))
            {
                oldProperty = string.Empty;
                directionsView.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else if (property != oldProperty)
            {
                oldProperty = property;
                directionsView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                oldDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                directionsView.SelectedIndex = 0;
                itemsView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(property, oldDirection));
            }
        }

        private void OnDirectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListSortDirection direction = (ListSortDirection)directionsView.SelectedItem;
            if (direction != oldDirection)
            {
                oldDirection = direction;
                itemsView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                itemsView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(oldProperty, direction));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It may just be my inexperience, but I feel like your example is doing something different than what I'm trying to do. It seems you have bound items that are all being triggered by property/direction changes, which can be handled with binding. But I have a radio button whose checked trigger should call another method that already exists, GridViewColumnGHeader_Click, but calling the method from the checked event gives me NullReferenceException because it takes a column object as an argument. I'm not understanding how your examples demonstrate a way to pass the column obj

Comment: @AlexD , My example shows that sorting Items does not require information about the column, but information about the property (or several properties) by which to sort. This property may or may not appear in the column. This does not affect sorting in any way.
For this reason, it is simply not necessary to "pass the column".